# On macOS Mojave using sourcetree / git-svn getting “Can't locate SVN/Core.pm in @INC ”

Tags: svn

I'm using macOS Mojave and want get a svn repo into a local git repo using sourcetree.

When I add a bookmark using sourcetree using SVN URL, thus sourcetree knows it's a SVN url, but when I click the clone button, it reports an error above error.

I don't how to get it through. Can anyone give me a pointer on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a similar error by separately installing subversion via homebrew:

```
brew install subversion
```

After that, `git svn` commands started working again.